# Functions in arrays/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, function

I am creating a program for practice where a button alternates colours between different pictures in a traffic light. However, when I click the button, nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="jscript.js"></script>
        <title>Task 3</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table align="center" style="border:groove;">
            <tr>
                <td> 
                     <button id="btn" onclick="switch()">Switch!</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <img src="black-circle.png" class="circles" id="c1"> </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr> 
                <td> <img src="black-circle.png" class="circles" id="c2"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <img src="black-circle.png" class="circles" id="c3"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS: (Very simple)

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.circles {
    width:53px;
    height:54px;
}   

#c1 {

}

#c2 {


}

#c3 {


}

#btn {


}
```

JavaScript:

```
var funcSelect = [displayRed(), displayYellow(), displayGreen()];
var funcSelectOperator = 0;
function switch() {
    ++funcSelectOperator;

    if (funcSelect == 3) {
        funcSelectOperator = 0;
    }

    funcSelect[funcSelectOperator];
    }

function displayRed() {
    document.getElementById("c1").src = "red-circle.png";
    document.getElementById("c2").src = "black-circle.png";
    document.getElementById("c3").src = "black-circle.png";
}

function displayYellow() {
    document.getElementById("c1").src = "black-circle.png";
    document.getElementById("c2").src = "yellow-circle.png";
    document.getElementById("c3").src = "black-circle.png";
}

function displayGreen() {
    document.getElementById("c1").src = "black-circle.png";
    document.getElementById("c2").src = "black-circle.png";
    document.getElementById("c3").src = "green-circle.png";
}
// JavaScript Document
```

Comment: Where is i defined? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Your condition if(funcSelect == 3) has a typo, it should be if(funcSelectOperator == 3)

Answer (score 0):

That's because of your switch function, you mix the variables roles and don't execute the function.
Also, remove the execution from your array of function.

```
var funcSelect = [displayRed, displayYellow, displayGreen];
var funcSelectOperator = 0;
function switchColor() {
    if(funcSelectOperator == 2)
        funcSelectOperator= 0;
    else ++funcSelectOperator;

    funcSelect[funcSelectOperator]();
}
```

Comment: rename the function switch by switchColor as "switch" is a special keyword

Comment: Move the declaration of your functions displayRed, displayYellow, displayGreen on the top, before making an array of them. They don't exists when you make the array.